# An indefinite houseguest

Tags: halacha, hachnasat-orchim-guests, shalom-bayit

Suppose one invites a guest over to stay by them for Shabbos or a few days.
Without chatting with the host, the guest doesn't "take the hint" and decides to stay.

The guest seemingly has no other options/ nowhere else to go- besides personal guilt, **are there any halachik issues with asking the guest to leave**?
<sub>(the length of the visit could be making the host uncomfortable, or create *shalom bayis* issues)</sub>

Comment: Maybe learning torah with the guest will help...like pesachim 49 http://tjpnews.com/rules-for-entertaining-guests/

Comment: Is כל מה שיאמר לך בעל הבית עשה חוץ מצא ([Pesachim 86b](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pesachim.86b.8?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)) the kind of answer you're looking for? (Apparently it seems more related to the guests' behavior than to what the host is allowed to do)

Comment: Will the guest's life be in danger if he is (respectfully) evicted?  Would funding his relocation exceed the homeowner's personal charity obligations (e.g. maaser kesafim)?

Comment: Somewhat similar: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/77940/170